# Using LmFuncs (Linear Regression) in Caret for Recursive Feature Elimination: How do I fix "same number of samples in x and y" error?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-caret, caret, rfe

I'm new to R and trying to isolate the best performing features from a data set of 247 columns (246 variables + 1 outcome), and 800 or so rows (where each row is one person's data) to create a predictive model.
I'm using caret to do RFE using `lmfuncs` - I need to use linear regression since the target variable continuous.

I use the following to split into test/training data (which hasn't evoked errors)

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(data$targetVar, p = .8, list = F)
train <- data[inTrain, ]
test <- data[-inTrain, ]
```

The resulting test and train files have even variables within the sets. e.g X and Y contain the same number samples / all columns are the same length

My control parameters are as follows (also runs without error)

```
control = rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, verbose = F, returnResamp = "all")
```

But when I run RFE I get an error message saying

**Error in rfe.default(train[, -1], train[, 1], sizes = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30), rfeControl = control) :
there should be the same number of samples in x and y**

My code for RFE is as follows, with the target variable in first column
`rfe_lm_profile <- rfe(train[, -1], train[, 1], sizes = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30), rfeControl = control)`

I've looked through various forums, but nothing seems to work.
This google.group suggests using an older version of Caret - which I tried, but got the same X/Y error https://groups.google.com/g/rregrs/c/qwcP0VGn4ag?pli=1
Others suggest converting the target variable to a factor or matrix. This hasn't helped, and evokes
**Warning message:
In createDataPartition(data$EBI_SUM, p = 0.8, list = F) :
Some classes have a single record**
when partitioning the data into test/train, and the same X/Y sample error if you try to carry out RFE.

Mega thanks in advance :)

p.s
Here's the dput for the target variable (EBI_SUM) and a couple of variables

```
data <- structure(list(TargetVar = c(243, 243, 243, 243, 355, 355), Dosing = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `QIDS_1 ` = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1), `QIDS_2 ` = c(3, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 3), `QIDS_3 ` = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: The error is not reproducible because `targetVar` is not a column of the `data` object created by `structure`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I've amended the dput now

Comment: I've revised my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object should not contain spaces:

```
library(caret)

data <- data.frame(
  TargetVar = c(243, 243, 243, 243, 355, 355),
  Dosing = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  QIDS_1 = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1),
  QIDS_2 = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  QIDS_3 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(data$TargetVar, p = .8, list = F)
train <- data[inTrain, ]
test <- data[-inTrain, ]
control <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, verbose = F, returnResamp = "all")
rfe_lm_profile <- rfe(train[, -1], train[, 1], sizes = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30), rfeControl = control)
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove spaces in my whole dataset? I've tried ```data <- apply(data, 2, str_remove_all, " ")``` but it seems to warp the dataset since I end up with **Error in `[.default`(tab, 1:m, 1:m) : subscript out of bounds**

Comment: colnames(data)  <- sapply(colnames(data),...)

Comment: I seem to still get the same x/y error when I apply this to my whole dataset. Is there a way that the size might be impacting it?

Comment: Do a binary search: Try to run it with the first 25, 50% of your rows and see at which row the error occurs.